# return django object with it's related instance as json

Tags: json, django

i've a Comment model and author ForeignKey  i want to return it in json with it's author profile picture i tried using manager but idk if something is wrong with it or it's the wrong approach

```
class CommentManager(models.Manager):
    def get_author_url(self, author):
        return self.get(url = author.pic.url)


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    DatePublished = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = CommentManager()
```

but what i get:

```
[{"id": 24, "post_id": 146, "author_id": 5, "content": "sb7", "DatePublished": "2021-07-29T06:40:38.752Z"}]
```

Comment: Are you using DRF ? If so, please provide the code for your Comment serializer.

Comment: @May.D NO, just normal django

Answer (score 0):

use serializers in views

```
from django.core import serializers

serializers.serialize('json',Comments.objects.filter(post=post))
```

Comment: that's my views code:

def GetPostComment(request, pk, counts=0):

 try:

  post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
  comments = list(Comment.objects.filter(post=post)[counts:][:counts+10].values())
  return JsonResponse(comments, safe=False)
 except:
  return JsonResponse({'message':"Whops something went wrong or the objects has been deleted!"})
idk where to use serializers

Comment: Dont post code in comments. Please include your view code in your question.